# Why isn't merge by distance allowing me to merge doubled vertices from different meshes?

Tags: mesh, vertices

Starting with a pyramid on top of a cube, selected all, and click merge by distance with an appropriately small distance with the intention of merging the points at the base of the pyramid and top of the cube:
[image]

As you can see, 13 verts selected and zero merged.
Now if I increase the merge distance to the point where it may merge multiple points on the same mesh, I get this:
[image]

So merge by distance IS working, it just doesn't want to be the tool that combines meshes. Why?

Answer (score 2):

The merge by distance work on single mesh data only. It doesn't need to be connected, but at least same mesh.

Usually you will need to **join two meshes first** and then merge doubles vertices. As an user dominant program, Blender should not do anything that user was not expecting for. It could be a good feature to make an option in operator. But multiple meshes editing is a new thing in 2.80, this is a new use case that developer need to consider.

So you might want to file your request as described [here](/questions/1190/best-place-to-put-feature-requests)